# Simple code Ended with this error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Tags: flutter, developer-tools

Just started flutter and ended up with this error. i made a signin.dart and run it through main.dart then i run the program the terminal endded up with this. here is my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart'; 
import 'package:flutters/view/signin.dart'; 

void main() { runApp(MyApp()); } 

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget { 
// This widget is the root of your application. 
@override Widget build(BuildContext context) { 
return MaterialApp( title: 'Flutter Demo', theme: ThemeData( primarySwatch: Colors.blue, ), home: SignIn(), ); 
} }
```

Comment: provide your code, so we can analyze it...

Comment: you can update your question and add your code to it ... I did it for you...

Answer (score 0):

your problem is due to having `main` function in your widget.
in each application, you only have to have one single `main` function. after that in each widget you can have `stateless` or `stateful` widgets that are children of your main widget.
for example use this instead:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart'; 
import 'package:flutters/view/signin.dart'; 

class SimpleWidget extends StatelessWidget { 
// This widget is the root of your application. 
@override Widget build(BuildContext context) { 
return Center(child:Text("Just A test"));
 }
```

then you can use `SimpleWidget` in you main.dart

Comment: i didn't understand